# Import just in root file but not in helper files Python

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am building a Flask API with a SQLAlchemy database. In my app.py file (the main file) I have all the necessary imports and setups, like so:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///data.db"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Th problem is, I would like to move this model

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20))
    password = db.Column(db.String(16))
```

to a separate file, to keep everything neat, but it inherits from the import, and from the

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

, but I cant have two of those, because the app crashes. In javascript for example, it is ppossible to declare a function that requires certain imports without importing them in that same file, as long as that function gets exported to another file where these requirements are met. In python though, it throws a `db is not defined` error. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention to the table name in User model. It should be

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_table_name'
    id = db.Column(db.integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20))
    password = db.Column(db.String(16))
```

replace user_table_name with the actual name of the table in your SQLite database.